# WPF - Does anyone actually use XBAPS and is there a good reason why they are used

Tags: wpf, xbap

Apart from the fact people get to view the app in a browser which may be familiar. Is there any actual compelling reason to use the XBAP model in WPF rather than a straightfoward stand alone WPF app.

All I can see are potential security issues and restrictions but no benefits. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have found they are used very often . . . in interview questions.

Comment: Offtopic: Kent, you think it's really important to know XBAP mechanics? I never ask these questions in interview. At least for me they don't show a candidate's potential... Maybe because we don't use XBAPs :)

Comment: I don't think it's important at all, which makes their prevalence in interviews ironic. I personally think ClickOnce or Silverlight are almost always the right choice - not XBAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used an XBAP, once.

We needed full-trust, and we needed the application to act as if it were browser hosted.  XBAP was the only real option we had, and I'm glad it was there.

Outside of this tiny nitch, Silverlight & Click Once are better all around options.

Answer (score 1):

In practice No and No would be the answers to your questions. I have never actually seen them used in production nor is there ever really a justified reason to use them.

As Kent mentioned Silverlight or Click Once is almost always a better option.

One could argue, in a full trust Windows only environment, XBAPS gives you the ability to leverage the full WPF framework with the flexibility of web deployment. Of course that is what Click once is for. However, in my experience ClickOnce is a nightmare for anything more then a simple, single application install so you might argue in favor of XBAP to avoid ClickOnce headaches.

But again, my response would be, Silverlight is likely a better choice.

Comment: Aren't all XBAPs ClickOnce apps themselves?

Answer (score 1):

We use it to have a single sourced solution for an application that can run in a browser but also as a desktop application. Both full trust.

Answer (score 1):

Actually a modular designed app consisting of xbap(s) communicating via webservice is very efficient.  This type of scenario would allow for execution of the modular pieces to run concurrent and in separate memory spaces.  This benefits the user and the application's developer(s).

The app would not run in an ie but rather a custom browser shell to control the flow and execution of the application itself.  It does seem like a lot of work when everything could simply run with in a single or multiple projects but this type of solution would be pertinent in large enterprise app(s).  The application Programmer(s) will be able to work on segments or distinct parts of the app which contain distinct functions, utilities, and capabilities.  The user never knows or realizes that each part is actually running independently because it appears seamless. The partial trust issue is eliminated because the shell is not an xbap and has full permission.  Now to the good stuff ... if there happens to be a fault (that never happens right?) other parts of the application continue to execute without failure.  Try-catch-finally work great until you miss one...  Last but not least no more complicate background thread processing it's in a browser and by default is async.  Most systems will have multiple windows open at a time each window simply contains a browser running an xbap.  Unique...Yes...Useful...Yes... It is a different approach but it is clean and simple.

Life is a race ... When you reach the finish line who will be there cheering for you and will you be proud of the race that was run?

Answer (score 1):

XBAPs using Partial Trust are useful if you have a requirement that the WPF client should be run without requiring admin privileges and without installing anything on the clients machine (disregarding the user's profile cache that is)

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking the same thing, here is my takeaway.

The main reason is the user experience, WPF apps are more powerful and easier to write than Silverlight. People will click on a web site, but will think twice about installing an application. An XBAP is very close to a website experience, and can out perform Click Once and Silverlight.

However since it only works for a very narrow user base, it would probably be best for intranet applications.

[WPF, XBAP, Silverlight - What do I use?](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2009/04/wpf_xbap_silverlight_what_do_i.html)